# mysql and vb 2010 zerofill integer data type

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an employee number datafield in MySQL with SMALLINT(4) datatype and zerofilled. In vb 2010, I have a textbox linked to that field but it is not displaying records with zerofills.

ex. "1" should be "0001" on my textbox.
    "43" should be "0043" and so on.

How do I go about doing this?

Note:
I linked mysql database on my data sources instead of coding it because I can't get the datareader to read and display all values in my textboxes.

Comment: By linked you mean it's databound?

Comment: yes, it is bound to my msyql database field("EMPNUM") with datatype smallint(4) and zerofilled.

Comment: Can you show the code for your binding, or did you use a wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program "thinks" it's an integer, it has no reason to display it in any way other than it would normally display an integer. You could do something like

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(4, "0"c)
End Sub
```

Note it will be called twice, once to pad the .Text and once more because padding the text has changed the .Text.

Comment: @ix3 You're welcome. Please mark it as the answer so that people can find it easily in future.